# Retrofit getting response message by Header and Field

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I wanna get the response message from my API

this is my API.kt

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("attendances/clock-in")
fun employeeClockIn(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String?,
    @Field("username ") username: String?,
    @Field("clock_in_ip_address") clkInIpadd : String?,
    @Field("clock_in_latitude") clkInLat : String?,
    @Field("clock_in_longitude") clkInLang: String?
): Call<ClockInRes>
```

and this is in my fragment to using post method to the api

```
var responseclkin = RetroFitClient().apiService.employeeClockIn("Bearer $passtoken",full_data?.username,getIpv4HostAddress(),location?.latitude.toString(),location?.longitude.toString())
                    println("tesklik : Bearer $passtoken ${full_data?.username} ${getIpv4HostAddress()} ${location?.latitude} + ${location?.longitude}")
                    tapin.setOnClickListener{
                        //isitapin.text= getCurrentDate()
                        responseclkin.enqueue(object : Callback<ClockInRes>{
                            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ClockInRes>, t: Throwable) { Toast.makeText(activity,"Jaringan error, silahkan coba lagi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
                            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ClockInRes>, response: Response<ClockInRes>) {
                                isitapin.text=response.body()?.data?.clock_in
                                Toast.makeText(activity,response.body()?.message , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }

                        })
                    }
```

and im using Header and Body in postman to get the respond here is the screenshot
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZifh.png)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWrMK.png)

I get Blank message on Toast

Comment: is response 200? Are you sure any of those fields and Header are not null?

Comment: I think you should try removing `@Headers("Accept: application/json")`  and
`@FormUrlEncoded` and use `data class` to construct your body

Comment: @SairajSawant i test on post man is not null and the response is 200

Comment: @Seanghay i have remove it and already make it to data class but still the same